# node child_process not writing everything to stdout

Tags: node.js, redis, child-process, redis-cli

I'm trying to use node's `spawn`/`exec` functions from the `child_process` module. But I'm noticing a strange difference between what I see in a real terminal and on the command line. Here's an example:

Terminal:

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> hmset hash name Jack age 33
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> hscan hash 0
1) "0"
2) 1) "name"
   2) "Jack"
   3) "age"
   4) "33"
```

In node.js:

```
const child = exec("redis-cli");
child.stdin.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
child.stdout.on("data", data => console.log(data.toString()));

child.stdin.write("hmset hash name Jack age 33\n"); // same as first command from cli example

await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));

child.stdin.write("hscan hash 0\n"); // same as second command from cli example

await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
```

This is what gets written to the console:

```
OK

0
name
Jack
age
33
```

In this case the numbers `1)`, `2)` etc. are missing. Any ideas how I can persuade `child_process` to also write them to the console? I'm guessing that this particular example is a quirk of how `redis-cli` is implemented, but the data must be going *some*where.

the `await new Promise(...)` calls are just to ensure that the previous command is finished for this simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is often the case, I figured this out within one minute of posting the question.

`redis-cli` tries to detect if the standard output is a terminal. This problem is solved by using

```
const child = exec("redis-cli --no-raw");
```

instead of

```
const child = exec("redis-cli");
```

[RTFM](https://redis.io/topics/rediscli).